# Creating Dynamic Folders based on Filename in Azure Data Factory DataFlow

Tags: azure, data-science, azure-data-factory

I am working on an Azure Data Factory data flow pipeline where I have a Sink activity. One of the columns in the sink contains filename information in the format "2023-07-19_diane_12345.csv". I want to use a pattern to extract specific data from the filename and create folders based on the following pattern yyyy/mm/dd.

I tried using the substring and lastIndexOf functions in the expression, but it is not working as expected.
Below parameter contains the filename

[image]

and in the SINK activity, I am trying to use expression builder to do that job but it says column not found.

[image]

It seems the expression I am building is for CopyActivity not for Dataflow I guess. Is there any other way to perform the job and create folders dynamically?

The pipeline looks like this

[image]

**Also the sink settings:**

[image]

Comment: First you mentioned that your file names are in a column and want to create folders by the extracting the yyyy/mm/dd from that column. But in the end you have used Get Meta data activity and ForEach and used an expression involving `item()`. Could you clarify which approach are you using? and what is your expected result?

Comment: Please ignore the ()item.name approach. filename column contains file information as (2023-07-19_kylehac.csv) and I am using column to store the filename. I want to use this to build an expression that can be used in Sink and files are stored in folders created dynamically. or any other way to do it efficiently. Please refer to my sink configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In derived column Add column with below expression builder

```
replace(substring(fileName ,0, 10),"-","/")
```

Here `fileName` is the column which stores the name of the file.

[image]

Configure the Sink settings as mentioned below:

- **File name option :**  `Name folder as column data`
- **Column data :** `<created column>`

[image]

The file will be stored in the `yyyy/mm/dd` format as mentioned below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution as it works but this solution is processing files twice. Means a file named 2023.07-19_abbey.csv is processed twice and see the data twice in folder. Is it something with the partition or with Get Metadata associated to the pipeline?

Comment: The issue is with Get Metadata, once check the source in dataflow.

Comment: I have configured Get Metadata with ChildItems in a directory where those logs files are stored. Is there anything I can do differently?

Comment: Why don't you try with copy activity is there any limitation?

Comment: I have to remove certain information from the logs file then move the data. I can not move the data directly as it has sensitive Information that needs to be filtered. I am using select transformation to remove certain attributes before sending to destination folder.

Comment: It seems not necessarily i have to iterate over files, if I configure my datset to that directory, Dataflow seems to read all the files automatically.